# How to Disable Async Callbacks when PopViewController

Tags: ios, ios6, callback, asihttprequest

I am building an iOS 6 application and I frequently run asynchronous HTTP requests to my server with delegates / callbacks. It's possible the user pops the top view controller (ie. the delegate to the request) before the request returns, and I thus get a `message sent to deallocated instance` error. I would like to be able to disable async callbacks that were assigned to the current delegate view controller when I pop it.

Is this possible?

What are other solutions?

Comment: Nil out the responder to the callback, rather than just praying it gets auto-nilled when deallocated.

Comment: You can post your comment as an answer. I blanked on the easy solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copying CodaFi's answer here since he did not:

Nil out the responder to the callback, rather than just praying it gets auto-nilled when deallocated.

Comment: If you'd add some code sample, would be really appreciated